# How to get only id using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want fetch only uid from input field using jquery.
I am not getting how to fetch only uid from that id
below is my input filed with auto increment

```
<input type="file" class="filedtat" name="abc_doc_'.$uid.'" id="abc_doc_'.$uid.'" class="form-control-file">
```

Nd front end will be

```
<input type="file" class="filedtat" name="abc_doc_0" id="abc_doc_0" class="form-control-file">
```

I am doing for only one input field like below

```
 $("#filedtat").change(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    $("#upload_purchase_doc"+id).val('');
                });
```

But i am getting whole id . I just want (0,1,2 etc)
i want make other field empty on that.
i just want only 0 from that id .. anyone have idea then let me know

Comment: just replace abc_doc_ with empty string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @GiacomoM cant do right now because lots of code already done . So not possible to evry place now. Any other way for this

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply replacing `abc_doc_` with empty string.

```
$("#filedtat").change(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('id').replace('abc_doc_', '');
    $("#upload_purchase_doc"+id).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can just replace the prefix string of the `id` to empty

then use the (.) instead of (#) for class

```js
$(".filedtat").change(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('id').replace('abc_doc_', '');
    console.log(id);
    $("#upload_purchase_doc"+id).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="form-control-file filedtat" name="abc_doc_0" id="abc_doc_0">
```